How do I don't let the path to show up after preview is ended in PowerPoint animation?
I have created an animation on PowerPoint. The sole and annoying problem I'm unable to fix is that the path shows up after the preview is ended.


What research have you done and what have you tried so far trying to fix this? What settings have you applied to this animation so far?

@music2myear I didn't found any relevant settings in the above ribbons. Even not in the right click on the path. Google search also didn't work. I'm beginning to think the path is uneraseable.

This is just the way animations work in PowerPoint. The path won't be visible in slide show view. And it's useful in more complex slides so you can tell where a motion path will end up (in case you need to match the starting point of the next animation with the end of the first one, for example).
